# Terminating an application programmatically using a file path in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, terminate

I want to terminate an application using the full file path via vb.net, yet I could not find it under Process. I was hoping for an easy Process.Stop(filepath), like with Process.Start, but no such luck.

How can I do so?

Comment: Why would I take a guy seriously whose profile says he's from Antartica and is making an MMORPG that will available for purchase soon.  BTW, you don't terminate applications through their file paths.  Instead you use the name of the process which is usually the name of the executable file.

Comment: The antarctica thing is a joke, the MMORPG is not for sale, my latest work (software, unrelated to the mmo) will be for sale soon though. Why should I take a guy seriously who cannot take a small joke? I know you do not terminate apps through their file paths, but I am asking about how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to look into each process' Modules property, and, in turn, check the filenames against your desired path.

Here's an example:

**VB.NET**

```
    Dim path As String = "C:\Program Files\Ultrapico\Expresso\Expresso.exe"
    Dim matchingProcesses = New List(Of Process)

    For Each process As Process In process.GetProcesses()
        For Each m As ProcessModule In process.Modules
            If String.Compare(m.FileName, path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
                matchingProcesses.Add(process)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each p As Process In matchingProcesses
        p.Kill()
    Next
```

**C#**

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\Ultrapico\Expresso\Expresso.exe";
var matchingProcesses = new List<Process>();
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    foreach (ProcessModule m in process.Modules)
    {
        if (String.Compare(m.FileName, path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            matchingProcesses.Add(process);
            break;
        }
    }
}

matchingProcesses.ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

**EDIT:** updated the code to take case sensitivity into account for string comparisons.

Comment: My application is in vb.net, I think your example was in c#. I am not very fluent in c#, so I cannot port this.

Comment: @Cyclone: no prob! BTW, I updated the code to ignore case sensitivity during the filepath comparison. Otherwise, you would've needed to pass in the path with the same case as the one defined in the module.

Answer (score 2):

try

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(nameOfExeFile).First().Kill()

This ignores the path of the file.

Comment: Any way to do it *with* the path though? Or, is there any way to find out the name of the file from the file path?